# A program designed to update fields in Service Now depending on type

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services

This is my first attempt at using asyncio, I don't believe I am using it properly and would like assistance using it to maximize efficiency. The current run time is between 20-22 seconds. I would like to reduce this as much as possible, thank you!

```
import asyncio
import aiosnow
from snow import snowCommands
#import login
import subprocess
import os
from pathlib import Path
import sys
import wmi
import requests
import time
import datetime
import winreg
import sys
import time
from formatting.formatter import Formatter
import logging
from snow.ComputerSupport import CompSup
from snow.computer import Computer
from snow.user import User
import wmi
import traceback
import re

#Settings
_version = "0.1.1" # Current Version
_filePath = os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]+'.exe' # returns PATH/TO/script.exe
_scriptname = Path(__file__).stem+'.exe' # returns script.exe
creator = "dmcanady" # Creator
contributors = [] # add anyone who assisted with the script

async def main():
    start_time = time.time()
    logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
    welcome = Formatter(_scriptname,_version,creator,contributors)
    welcome.header()
    username = ""
    while True:
        #username,password = login.login()
        username = input("Username: ")
        password = input("Password: ")
        if "@" in username:
            print("Usernames cannot be an email")
        else:
            break
    __instance__ = 'libertydev.service-now.com' # URL for service now
    serviceNow = aiosnow.Client(__instance__, basic_auth=(username,password)) # creates serviceNow session for creds provided
    ticket = await genTicket(serviceNow)
    await userAccept(username,ticket)
    ticketTypes = {"Assignment":__assignment__,"Return":__return__,"Repair":__repair__,"Life Cycle Management":__LCM__}
    await ticketTypes[ticket["CS"].cat_item](ticket)
    print(time.time()-start_time)
    welcome.footer()
    

async def genTicket(serviceNow:object):
    # Validates CS Number #
    valid = False
    while valid == False:
        print("CS Format: CSXXXXXXX")
        CSNumber = input("CSNumber: ")
        valid = bool(re.match("^CS[0-9]{7}",CSNumber))
    # Attempts to get ticket #
    try:
        CS = await CompSup(serviceNow,CSNumber)
        # Validates that the ticket is available #
        if((CS.state).key == 1 and CS.assigned_to == None and CS.u_wi_primary_tech == None):
            while True:
                accept = input("Do you want to accept this ticket (y/n): ")
                if accept == "y":
                    Comp = await Computer(serviceNow,CS.u_asset)
                    assigned = await User(serviceNow,CS.assigned_to)
                    if CS.assigned_to == CS.u_wi_primary_tech:
                        tech = assigned
                    else:
                        tech = await User(serviceNow,CS.u_wi_primary_tech)
                    customer = await User(serviceNow,CS.requested_for)
                    LCMComp = await Computer(serviceNow,CS.u_asset_returned)
                    # Returns ticket information if available #
                    return {"CS":CS,"computer":Comp,"assigned":assigned,"technician":tech,"Customer":customer,"LCM computer": LCMComp}
                elif accept == "n":
                    print("You have declined the ticket, please restart when you want one.")
        # if ticket is unavailable
        else:
            print("Ticket is not available (not in open or is already assigned). Please selected another ticket.")
            sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.getLogger().exception(e)

async def userAccept(username,computerInfo):
    await computerInfo["CS"].updateCS(["assigned_to","u_wi_primary_tech"],[username,username])
    await computerInfo["assigned"].__init__(computerInfo["CS"].serviceNow,computerInfo["CS"].assigned_to)
    await computerInfo["technician"].__init__(computerInfo["CS"].serviceNow,computerInfo["CS"].u_wi_primary_tech)
    await computerInfo["CS"].updateCS(["state","u_substate"],[2," "])
    print("Ticket Type 1:",computerInfo["CS"].cat_item)
    #Will be used to verify the correct computer is being used.
    print("verifying device's serial")
    c = wmi.WMI()
    if computerInfo["computer"].sys_id != None:
        try:
            serial = computerInfo["computer"].serial_number
            print("Ticket Type:",computerInfo["CS"].cat_item)
        except:
            serial = computerInfo["computer"].u_asset
            print("Ticket Type:",computerInfo["CS"].cat_item)
            
    elif computerInfo["computer"].sys_id == None:
        try:
            serial = computerInfo["computer"].serial_number
            print("Ticket Type:",computerInfo["CS"].cat_item)
        except:
            serial = computerInfo["computer"].u_asset
            print("Ticket Type:",computerInfo["CS"].cat_item)
            
    cSerial = c.Win32_ComputerSystem()[0].Name
    print("Ticket Type:",computerInfo["CS"].cat_item)
    
    if(serial != cSerial):
        print("Please run me on {0}.".format(serial))
        print("Exiting...")
        input("Press any key to continue")
        print("Ticket Type:",computerInfo["CS"].cat_item)
        #sys.exit(0)

# opens programs and features for tech
def uninstallApp(ticketType):
    print('----')
    # if ticket is a repair, it looks for non standard applications
    if ticketType == "repair":
        message = '  Please uninstall any applications not standard.'
        proType = 'non-standard'
    # if ticket is a return it looks for licensed applications
    elif ticketType == "return":
        message = '  Please uninstall any licensed applications.'
        proType = 'licensed'
    print(message)
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system('cmd /c appwiz.cpl') # opens programs and features
    while True:
        # Verifies with tech that changes have been made
        removed = input("have all {0} programs been removed (y/n): ".format(proType))
        if removed == "y":
            return True
        elif removed == "n":
            print("I will open the window for you...")
            time.sleep(1)
            os.system('cmd /c appwiz.cpl') # opens programs and features
        else:
            print("Please respond y or n.")

# Checks to see if computer needs to have an IPU ran
async def reimage():
    global _OSVersion
    key = r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion"
    val = r"ReleaseID"

    with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, key) as key:
        _OSVersion = int(winreg.QueryValueEx(key,val)[0])
    if _OSVersion < 1909:
        print("Please run IPUInstaller.exe to update to newest version.")
    elif _OSVersion >=1909:
        print("This computer is 1909 or newer!")

# Restarts device
async def restart():
    for i in reversed(range(11)):
        print("This device will restart in: {:02}".format(i))
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Restarting for reimaging...")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("shutdown /r /t 10") # set to restart computer after 10 seconds

async def setState(computerInfo,state,__sysid__ = ""):
    if __sysid__ == "":
        __sysid__ = computerInfo["computer"].sys_id
    states = {
        "In Use" : {"install_status":1,"substatus":"","assigned_to":computerInfo["CS"].requested_for},
        "Return" : {"install_status":16,"substatus":"","stockroom":"IT Helpdesk Walkin Support"},
        "LCMed" : {"install_status":6,"substatus":"pending_transfer","stockroom":"IT Helpdesk Walkin Support"}
        }
    if state == "In Use":
         # Assigns customer as assigned to
        await computerInfo["computer"].updateHardware(__sysid__,["assigned_to"], [states[state]["assigned_to"]])
    else:
        await computerInfo["computer"].updateHardware(__sysid__,["stockroom"],[states[state]["stockroom"]])    
    # changes status to in use
    await computerInfo["computer"].updateHardware(__sysid__,["install_status","substatus"],[states[state]["install_status"],states[state]["substatus"]])

# checks if warranty is expired or not.
async def warrantyCheck(computerInfo):
    if computerInfo["computer"].sys_id == None:
        print("This device is a personal device.")
        expire_raw = None
        check = computerInfo["CS"].u_manufacturer.value
    elif computerInfo["computer"].sys_id != None:
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        expire_raw = computerInfo["computer"].warranty_expiration
        check = computerInfo["computer"].display_name
    if expire_raw == None:
        if "Dell" in check:
            site = "https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us?app=warranty"
        elif "HP" in check:
            site = "https://support.hp.com/us-en/checkwarranty"
        elif "Lenovo" in check:
            site = "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/warrantylookup#/"
        elif "Microsoft" in check:
            site = "https://mybusinessservice.surface.com/en-US/CheckWarranty/CheckWarranty"
        else:
            site = "your manufacture's site"
        print("No warranty information avaliable")
        print("Please go to {0} to check current warranty info!".format(site))
        # Connection for warranty API to check current warranty information
    else:
        exp = datetime.datetime.strptime(expire_raw, "%Y-%m-%d")
        if exp > today:
            print("device's warranty expires %s" % exp)
        elif exp == today:
            print("device's warranty expires today")
        elif exp < today:
            print("device's warranty expired %s" % exp)

#Processes by ticket type
async def __assignment__(computerInfo):
    print("I am an assignment")
    await setState(computerInfo = computerInfo,state = "In Use")
    # Requested steps to take after
    print("Please run auto-assign")
    print("Check to make sure drivers have been updated.")

async def __return__(computerInfo):
    print("I am a return")
    await setState(computerInfo = computerInfo,state = "Return")
    # Returns true if tech states they uninstalled all licensed programs
    if uninstallApp("return"):
        assoc = input("Is there an associated assignment Ticket (y/n): ")
        # if there is an associated assignment, reboots with intent of reimage
        if assoc == "y":
            await computerInfo["CS"].updateCS("work_notes","System checked for licensed applications.")
            print("Please ensure an ethernet cable is securely connected before proceeding.")
            await computerInfo["CS"].updateCS("work_notes","begin Win 10 1909 Fac/Staff imaging process via IPv4 PXE")
        # Otherwise reboots with intent to erase all data
        print("Computer will restart shortly to erase data.")
        decide = input("continue (y/n): ")
        if decide == "y":
            await restart()
        else:
            pass
            
async def __repair__(computerInfo):
    print("I am a repair")
    await reimage() # Checks current OS
    await warrantyCheck(computerInfo) # Checks warranty status
    # Checks for unauthorized programs
    if uninstallApp("repair"):
        await computerInfo["CS"].updateCS("work_notes","System checked for nonstandard applications.")
        print("Check to make sure drivers have been updated.")


async def __LCM__(computerInfo):
    print("I am an LCM")
    print(computerInfo["computer"].install_status.key)
    if computerInfo["computer"].install_status.key != 1:
        await setState(computerInfo = computerInfo,__sysid__ = computerInfo["computer"].sys_id,state = "In Use")
    else:
        print("It appears the device is already in use...")
        print("Let me check who")
        if computerInfo["computer"].assigned_to == computerInfo["CS"].requested_for:
            pass
        else:
            print("Oh no, looks like someone else is currently assigned...")
            print("Let me correct that!")
            user = computerInfo["CS"].requested_for
            await computerInfo["computer"].updateHardware(computerInfo["computer"].sys_id,["assigned_to"],[user])
        print("Awesome! Looks like the proper user is assigned.")
        print("Let me check on the return device.")
    while True:
        resp = input("Do you have the original device (y/n): ")
        if resp == "y":
            await setState(computerInfo = computerInfo,__sysid__ = computerInfo["LCM computer"].sys_id,state = "LCMed")
            break
        elif resp == "n":
            print("Please restart when you have the device...")
            await computerInfo["CS"].updateCS("work_notes","Awaiting returned device.")
            break

# Starts loop
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pathlib

```
_filePath = os.path.splitext(__file__)[0]+'.exe'
```

is better expressed as

```
from pathlib import Path

FILE_PATH = Path(__file__).with_suffix('.exe')
```

Note that since it's a global constant, it should be capitalized.

### Pre-declaration?

Delete `username = ""`.

### Password security

Do *not* use `input` to capture a password. It's visible to onlookers. Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html instead.

### Parens and comparisons

```
if((CS.state).key == 1 and CS.assigned_to == None and CS.u_wi_primary_tech == None):
```

has a few issues:

- Don't use outer parens. This isn't Java.
- Use `is None` instead of `== None` since `None` is a singleton in Python.
- Don't use parens around `(CS.state)`, either.

### Mystery hangs

Why does `uninstallApp` (which should be `uninstall_app`) do this?

```
time.sleep(1)
```

Don't make your user wait pointlessly.

### External processes

Don't use `os.system`. Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html instead.

### More extraneous code

```
    else:
        pass
```

can be deleted.

### Expression negation

```
    if computerInfo["computer"].assigned_to == computerInfo["CS"].requested_for:
        pass
    else:
```

should just be

```
if computerInfo["computer"].assigned_to != computerInfo["CS"].requested_for:
```